# How can I know who caused an interruptedExeption? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, sleep, interrupt

I'm using interrupt() in my code to signal from a thread to another to wake up from "endless" (Maximum time) sleep and verify a condition in a while.
I'm using also monitor (synchronized block, notify and wait) and synchronized method. I wrote my code in the way that some thread sleeps until they got an interrupt but some interrupt wake up thread when they should not be awaken (they must simulate they are doing other things sleeping). The problem is that I'm not able to find the thread that do interrupt() when it should not, how can I found it?

Is a good way to code using interrupt() in this way?

That's the code in which sleep get interrupted but should not

```
private void medicalVisit(int number) {
    long sleepTime = (long) ((Math.random() * 2 + 0.5) * 1000); // 500 <= sleepTime (in msec) <= 2500
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" ERROR, interrupt from sleep, id: 2 (medicalVisit)");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(this.getName()+" - "+number+"° medical visit ended");
}
```

This is an example of code that launch an interrupt

```
private void handlerYellowPatient() {
    Iterator<Patient> patientIt = yellows.iterator();
    while(patientIt.hasNext()) {
        Patient p = patientIt.next();
        p.itsTurn = true;
        p.interrupt();
        yellows.remove(p);
    }
}
```

And this an example of code "consuming" interrupt properly

```
private void waitUntilItsTurn(int number) {
    // simulating the period of time before entering in guard
    long sleepTime = (long) ((Math.random() * 2 + 0.5) * 1000); // 500 <= sleepTime (in msec) <= 2500
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // must not be awaken while here
        System.out.println(this.getName()+" ERROR MAYBE, interrupt from sleep, id: 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WMan.addPatient(this, WMan);
    while (!itsTurn) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // WMan handlerRedPatient interrupt#1
            System.out.println(this.getName()+" - the wait is over, it's my turn for the "+number+"° times");
        }   
    }
    itsTurn = false;
}
```

Hoping these code can help

Comment: can you show your code, please?

Comment: Why use `interrupt` to wake something, when this is exactly what `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` is for?

Comment: I don't want to use locks everytime I want threads comunicate which each other. I don't want to use locks if I can use monitor

Comment: "Is a good way to code using interrupt() in this way?" No. Essentially, you should *rarely* be using anything directly on `Thread`, or the primitive concurrency methods on `Object` for that matter. They're *too* primitive. There are higher-level concurrency classes in `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: "I don't want to use locks everytime I want threads comunicate which each other" But you need to. Sleeps and interruptions don't give you memory visibility. Perhaps you don't need locks themselves, but you need something which creates a happens-before.

Comment: "I want threads comunicate which each other." How do you think `interrupt()` is acting? the other thread is sleeping and cannot communicate. Instead, you order operating system to awake it. The classical approach `synchronized/wait/notify` acts in the same way, as well as `ReentrantLock/condition`. But in traditional approaches, you can pass additional information, and, as @AndyTurner noted,  happens-before relationships are satisfied automatically.

Comment: yeah sleep/interruption is not the best fit. probably better to have some actor type thing where each process has its own mailbox (a queue) where it can get messages. what you're doing is excruciatingly painful for multiple reasons.

Comment: I thought using lock was _too_ primitive as well. So I should use locks and monitor also if I haven't a critical section? I didn't know that was the best solution. Thanks for all comments

Comment: I would _not_ use `interrupt` as a means of communication between threads. If I want a thread to wait for something, then I would use wait/notify or I would use some higher-level synchronization object like a blocking queue or a semaphore. I don't trust `interrupt` because if the interrupt is delivered while my thread is calling into some 3rd-party library, I have no way of knowing that the library handles the interrupt in a clean way. Library authors may have assumed that interruption means that the process is shutting down, and they may have left globals in an unuseable state.